# OrmLite Cascade Delete

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I read a couple of questions on stackoverflow about this but they didnt help

How to delete `ProductPhoto`s when deleting certain `Products`?

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Products")
public class Product{

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection<ProductPhoto> productPhotos;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "ProductPhotos")
public class ProductPhoto {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Product product;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I went around this in the past was by enabling foreign key support in the db with the `PRAGMA` keyword. As far as I know, foreign keys are supported but you need to enable them. The SQL for it:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

I used to do this on the `SQLOpenHelper` on `void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db)`, so something like:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

I did this only when the db was writable.

As for your models, they seem to be correctly setup.

**Note**: There's 2 down sides here as far as I know. First it's only support from android 2.2 (inclusive to my best knowledge) due to the sqlite version. Also google seems to recommend to do this somewhere else, but it was in methods supported only after api 16 so I kept doing it inside `db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");`.

Comment: Okay, I will enable the foreign keys, however, how do I do the deletion itself? If it is enabled and I use the ProductDAO to delete a product, will it automatically delete the ProductPhoto's?

Comment: yes, it should be a matter of simply deleting one of the objects from Product

Comment: Will give it a try in a few days when the API is ready and will let you know how it worked out. Thanks!